# unisharp file-manager for laravel problem

Tags: php, laravel, file-manager

I have a problem using uniSharp Filemanager , after implementing everything from the Installation page of unisharp , TinyMce works fine , uploading works fine , but after uploading something , I dont see anything...No thumbnails , no images(I see the names of the files but cant do anything with them) seems like maybe it doesnt move the files correctly.
I have already used Storage:link , used base_directory in lfm file but no luck.

Footer Script :

```
 <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var editor_config = {
        path_absolute : "/",
        selector: "textarea#editor",
        directionality:"rtl",
        plugins: [
            "advlist directionality autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | ltr rtl",
        relative_urls: false,
        file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

            var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
            if (type == 'image') {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
            } else {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
            }

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                file : cmsURL,
                title : 'Filemanager',
                width : x * 0.8,
                height : y * 0.8,
                resizable : "yes",
                close_previous : "no"
            });
        }
    };

    tinymce.init(editor_config);
</script>
```

And my lfm file :

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Documentation for this config :
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| online  => http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/config
| offline => vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/docs/config.md
 */

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'use_package_routes'       => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Shared folder / Private folder
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If both options are set to false, then shared folder will be activated.
    |
     */

    'allow_private_folder'     => true,

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHandler class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHandler::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'private_folder_name'      => UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,

    'allow_shared_folder'      => true,

    'shared_folder_name'       => 'shares',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Folder Names
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'base_directory' => 'public',
    'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
    'files_folder_name' => 'files',

    'folder_categories'        => [
        'file'  => [
            'folder_name'  => 'files',
            'startup_view' => 'grid',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
            ],
        ],
        'image' => [
            'folder_name'  => 'photos',
            'startup_view' => 'list',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
                'application/pdf',
                'text/plain',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pagination
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'paginator' => [
        'perPage' => 30,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'disk'                     => 'public',

    'rename_file'              => false,

    'alphanumeric_filename'    => false,

    'alphanumeric_directory'   => false,

    'should_validate_size'     => false,

    'should_validate_mime'     => false,

    // behavior on files with identical name
    // setting it to true cause old file replace with new one
    // setting it to false show `error-file-exist` error and stop upload
    'over_write_on_duplicate'  => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Thumbnail
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => true,

    'thumb_folder_name'        => 'thumbs',

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes'         => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    'thumb_img_width'          => 200, // px

    'thumb_img_height'         => 200, // px

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'file_type_array'          => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
     */
    'php_ini_overrides'        => [
        'memory_limit' => '256M',
    ],
];
```

[What the problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzjBs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

change file "config/filesystems.php" line 40:

```
root' => storage_path('app/public'),
```

with

```
'root' => storage_path('../public/storage'),
```